# Send push notification from web server to a desktop software (Windows)

Tags: delphi, web-development-server

This is a theoretical question. I first need help to know (understand) how to achieve my needs, so I can use the right keywords in a new research. Btw, sorry about my english, it is not my native language.

Well, I have a desktop (Windows) software created with Delphi and I'd like to allow users to change it configuration remotely, by a web page (PHP) or maybe using another software module (in a different place/lan/wan). E.g.: the user logs in my website, disable some checkbox, save and automatically the software installed in his computer updates itself. The main issue here is how to stabilish the communication (webserver -> desktop software), not the configuration.

Few days ago I heard about Android push notifications (Firebase Cloud Messaging) and think this is exacly what I need. So was wondering if there is something similar that I can use with Delphi and desktop softwares, but found nothing in Google.

Please, can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: @kobik, you are right! My question is mainly about how this automaticaly communication web server -> software will occur once knowing the software will be behind a router, firewall, etc., the same way a mobile device is when receiving a push notification using the Google Firebase Cloud Messaging...

Comment: Look up `long polling` with HTTP

Comment: @mjn42, I did a quick research and long polling looks promising. Now I will research if it could be implemented with Delphi. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like the WNS (Windows Push Notification Services) from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

Answer (score -3):

I think the simpliest way is to create an ini-file. You can configure the ini-file in your web-application and when the user starts your program it looks for an new ini-file, load it and use it. To manipulate your exe-file is maybe a bad idea, because of anti virus software which will block such activities.

Comment: I need a way to create a web -> software instant communication

Comment: `The main issue here is how to stabilish the communication (webserver -> desktop software), not the configuration.`

Comment: It remains open the purpose of this communication. Why should a user input data in a Web-app instead of enter it in the desktop app directly. I think my answer remains correct, because it makes no difference if you poll your web-app by http or if you look for an ini-file